# Need to create a loop using HTML5 canvas and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am using a jQuery carousel to display 38 different magnifications/positions of a large SVG image.  I would ideally like to use some sort of loop to go through all the different sizes, draw to an individual `canvas` and place one in each of the `li`'s in my carousel. Can anyone help me achieve this.  Here's what I tried:

```
function drawSlides() {
    for (var i = 1; i <= 38; i++) {

    var currentCanvas = 'myCanvas_' + slideNumber;

    // initialise canvas element

    var canvas_i = document.getElementById('' + currentCanvas + '');
        var context = canvas_i.getContext('2d');

    // position of SVG – these measurements are subject to change!
    var destX_i = -6940;
    var destY_i = -29240;
    var destWidth_i = 9373;
    var destHeight_i = 30000;
    context.drawImage('/path/image.svg', 
       destX_i, destY_i, destWidth_i, destHeight_i);

    // white rectangle background  – these are constant
    var topLeftCornerX_i = 453;               
        var topLeftCornerY_i = -10;
    var width_i = 370;
    var height_i = 480;
    context.beginPath();
    context.rect(topLeftCornerX_i, topLeftCornerY_i, width_i, height_i);
    context.fillStyle = "rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)";
    context.fill();

    // orange vertical line – these elements are constant
    context.moveTo(453, 0);
    context.lineTo(453, 460);
    context.lineWidth = 2;
    context.strokeStyle = "#f5d7cb";
    context.stroke();

    //orange ball  – these are constant
    var centerX_ball_i = 453;
    var centerY_ball_i = 323;
    var radius = 99;
    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(centerX_ball_i, centerY_ball_i, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
    var grd_ball_i = context.createLinearGradient(224, 354, 422, 552);
    grd_ball_i.addColorStop(0, "#f5d7cb"); // light orange
    grd_ball_i.addColorStop(1, "#ff4900"); // dark orange
    context.fillStyle = grd_ball_i;
    context.fill();
    }            
};

drawSlides();
```

Comment: You need to be more clear about the visual effect you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Also providing a link to a jsfiddle.net setup with the code you have would be nice.

Comment: I am trying to populate a scrolling carousel (tinyCarousel) with 38 toggleable/scrolling slides each showing an image at a different size. As the main image i'm using is an SVG, I opted for embedding it within canvas. Does that make sense?

Comment: You posted the code you have - nice work - but since it doesn't stand on its own we can't test it, and you haven't explained what trouble you are having. Do you just need help procedurally creating 38 `<canvas>` elements, appending them to unique `<li>` elements, and drawing the same SVG image on each canvas?

Comment: Yes, that's about the meat of it. Apologies for not including the complete code. It's part of a PHP page, and I'm not sure if it'll bug out. Anyway, the main hurdle I have is to figure out the logic of creating a loop that runs through 38 <li>s drawing a new canvas to each one. I'll figure it out somehow. Thanks for your comments and advice, and I'll bear your points in mind for future postings to SO :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should get you moving:

```js
var numCarouselItems = 38;
var myUL  = document.getElementById('carousel');
var items = myUL.childNodes;
var img = new Image;
img.onload = function(){
  for (var i=0;i<numCarouselItems;++i){
    // Find the nth li, or create it
    var li = items[i] || myUL.appendChild(document.createElement('li'));

    // Find the nth canvas, or create it
    var canvas = li.getElementsByTagName('canvas')[0] ||
                 li.appendChild(document.createElement('canvas'));
    canvas.width  =   1; // Erase the canvas, in case it existed
    canvas.width  = 320; // Set the width and height as desired
    canvas.height = 240;
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    // Use your actual calculations for the SVG size/position here
    ctx.drawImage( img, 0, 0 );
  }
}

// Be sure to set your image source after your load handler is in place
img.src = "foo.svg";
```

Comment: Thanks, man. I tried your code but couldn't get it to work, so I went back to the drawing board a little, and used some CSS to separate the images that weren't being drawn properly. Everything's working OK now, but I'm getting a "canvas is null" error, even though the canvas elements are OK. May start a new thread :S